# PWM generation using Arduino uno

Tags: pwm

How to obtain four PWM outputs at 100 kHz using an arduino uno board? The requirement is that all four PWM outputs should have controllable duty ratios individually.

Comment: There's a ton of examples in the web. Google doesn't bite, use it.

Comment: This is a arduino user level question, nothing about electrical engineering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment to Dmitry Grigoryev’s answer you wrote:

```c++
void setup()
{
    TCCR2A = 0x23;
    TCCR2B = 0x09;
    OCR2A = 159;
    pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    OCR2B = 80;
}
```

It seems you already have the solution to your problem: that's exactly
the way to do it!

Well, there is a catch: since you are using `OCR2A` to define the period
of your timer, this means you are left with a single PWM channel, where
the duty cycle is controlled by `OCR2B`. Given that the Arduino Uno has
only three timers, it would seem you can only have up to three PWM
channels at 100 kHz.

But there is a solution. Timer 1 has a feature the other timers
don't have: you can define its period using using the input capture
register `ICR1` instead of `OCR1A`. This leaves you both output compare
registers available for PWM. For this you have to set the timer into
waveform generation mode 14, i.e. fast PWM with TOP = ICR1.
Now you can have your four channels, with Timer 0 driving
pin 5, Timer 2 driving pin 3, and Timer 1 driving
pins 9 and 10.

Some caveats:

- As already pointed out by Dmitry Grigoryev, your PWM resolution is
  slightly reduced.
- By reconfiguring Timer 0, you loose the Arduino Timekeeping function
  `millis()`, `micros()` and, `delay()`. You could write your own ISR to
  count the overflows of some other timer, but it would be called every
  10 µs: even if it is very short it would eat a non-trivial
  fraction of your CPU power.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for the help. I'm trying to implement as you mentioned. I'll get back to you with some results.

Answer (score 2):

You can't squeeze 100kHz out of an Arduino without a major software rewrite (at which point you will be using an AtMega chip rather than Arduino). `analogWrite` defaults to ~500Hz and can be boosted to [62.5kHz](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/TimerPWMCheatsheet) on some Arduino models, and only for 2 pins. Other PWM pins are capped at 31.4kHz.

You can achieve 100kHz PWM by toggling pins manually and busy-waiting, but you won't be able to do anything else during this. Or you can make use of interrupts, which is a big leap from Arduino ecosystem as I already said.

Comment: setup()
{TCCR2A = 0x23;
 TCCR2B = 0x09; 
 OCR2A = 159;  
 pinMode(3, OUTPUT); 
}  loop()
{
 OCR2B = 80;

Comment: I used the following code to generate 100 khz pwm signal-
setup()
{
 TCCR2A = 0x23;
 TCCR2B = 0x09;
 OCR2A = 159;
 pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
}
loop()
{
 OCR2B = 80;
I have to drive 4 MOSFET's simultaneously for my project to achieve multiple O/P dc-dc converter. Probably an arduino Mega would work?

Comment: @ParikshitDeshmukh You're sacrificing resolution for speed here. You get your 100 kHz, but only 160 distinct PWM duty cycles instead of 256.